# SNS to notify column changes in Amazon RDS database table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-sns

is there a way to fire a Amazon SNS notification(directly, or via a lambda function) of change of a column in my table of a sql server database hosted on Amazon RDS?

Thanks!

Comment: This article lists the RDS events. Column changes is not listed; http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.html

Comment: Yes, i saw that but couldn't find it as well.. Can lambda help here?

Comment: If RDS does not generate an event, Lambda will not be able to respond to one. You will need to modify your code that modifies your tables to do this.